# What changed with Cygwin from 1.7 to 2.5?

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-x

I upgraded my Cygwin and I'm having a little trouble.
As usual, an upgrade utterly breaks everything that is part of my standard workflow.

I figured out the Menu issue, however, my xterm no longer opens automagically
and when I do open an xterm, all the settings that I had made: fg color, bg color, font size are no longer appearing.

I could use some insights so I can quickly get my workflow back and return to productive operations.

The other thing that seems to be broken, my SecureShell instance was automagically working with my remote linux X Apps, and now after the "upgrade" the X11 port forwarding fails.

Is there some configuration issue that I need to handle manually now?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are asking if someone has written a guide "how to upgrade your specific configuration along your specific upgrade path", then the answer is "the chances are very slim". If you're asking to write such a guide for you, it's asking too much. To troubleshoot your specific problems, you have given way too little information and shown no own effort. So for this particular question, I can really say nothing beyond what I said.

Answer (score 0):

[What's new and what changed in Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new.html) has an extensive list of core changes for all releases.

Individual packages are maintained independently and generally strive to be close to upstream.

Answer (score 0):

all the changes are reported on the Announce mailing list

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/